# Error pushing code to the scratch org using DX command in the CI/CD pipline

Tags: sfdx-plugin, jenkins, cicd, jenkinsfile

I have set up a ci/cd pipeline using Jenkins. I am running a couple of commands using the Jenkins file.

The commands like `creating a scratch org`, `generating a password for the scratch org`, `converting source code to mdapi` but the pushing code command is failing due to **variable not found error**.

But all the variable fields are there. The scratch org is using a namespace. All the commands are working fine in my locals.

Please advise what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you share your Jenkins script?

Comment: I am doing it through pom.xml and the pom.xml is being executed by Jenkins using the docker hosted on client personal server.

Comment: We are using the docker salesforce CLI image to create a SFDX container to run the salesforce DX command.

Comment: @user1067017, I think I have figured out why the error is coming up. I have namespace registered with the devhub but the scratch orgs are getting created without the namespace.